# What is the purpose of calling Invoke from the specific control that's affected?

Tags: vb.net, invoke

Say I've got the following sub that simply adds passed items to a ListView control:

```
Private Sub AddListItem(ByVal item As ListViewItem)
    UIList.Items.Add(item)
End Sub
```

And I use that from a BackgroundWorker thread, like so:

```
UIList.BeginInvoke(Sub() AddListItem(lvItem))
```

Well quite by accident I've just discovered that it doesn't seem to matter *which* control is used to call the `Invoke\BeginInvoke` method, or even if I omit a control altogether and just call the method directly – which I assume just uses `Me.<Method>` behind the scenes – it doesn't seem to matter. The code still works.

So, is using the affected control to call the method just a way to make following the code easier? What, if any, are the other advantages? And are there certain pitfalls one needs to be aware of when using a different control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ILSpy](http://ILSpy.net) and digging down the [`Control.Invoke` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx), an excerpt is

```
...
UnsafeNativeMethods.PostMessage(
    new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), 
    Control.threadCallbackMessage, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
 ...
```

In addition, [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx):

> The Invoke method searches up the control's parent chain until it
>   finds a control or form that has a window handle if the current
>   control's underlying window handle does not exist yet. If no
>   appropriate handle can be found, the Invoke method will throw an
>   exception. Exceptions that are raised during the call will be
>   propagated back to the caller.

So usually it shouldn't matter which control you post to.

Personally, I use the "nearest" control I can get to call the `Invoke` method.

Comment: Damn! I reckoned to have read that MSDN page but somehow missed that remark. Thank you anyway. :)